# difflib, type error int object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, iterable, difflib

[Link to the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPw0O.png)

```
import random
import difflib
number = int(input("How many words do you want to practise?"))
words = [*3000 word array*]

for x in range(0, number):
    text_1 = random.randint(0, 3000)
    z = words[text_1]
    print(z)
    text_2 = str(input("Type:"))
    seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=text_1, b=text_2)
    difference = seq.quick_ratio()
    difference = round(difference, 1)
    print(str(difference) + "% Match")

 print("Thank you!")
```

*The Error message I kept getting: (Line 12)*

for elt in self.a:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I have been on a good flow with this program but reached this wall and have tried so many different ways of figuring it out but really couldn't. The program is meant to be a typing test/practice thing. I hope anyone here can help me figure out a solution for my error message, or any suggestions, in general, would be great.

Note:
I am very new to this website, so I apologize if any 'format' I use is wrong.

Comment: Code _must_ be posted as _text_ in your question, not as external links or images, or in comments. Regardless, from what it looks like, you're trying to use `SequenceMatcher` to compare a user-inputted string to a randomly generated integer. Do you mean to be comparing the _string representation_ of the random integer?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you give an example of the text you're inputting?

Comment: just added it, sorry im new to this site

Comment: @RandomDavis there isn't any integers in the code, the idea is a random text is generated and you type in that text, and then the two strings are compared. 
(Typing test/typing practice)

Comment: @Atassi you say that, yet `text_1` is an integer. Did you mean to pass `z` instead of `text_1`, like `a=z`?

Comment: @RandomDavis you just cured an hour of headaches a very stupid mistake. Thank you so much. The fixed code:

for x in range(0, number):
    z = random.randint(0, 3000)
    text_1 = words[z]
    print(text_1)

Comment: @Atassi that's why using a debugger is such an important fundamental tool of programming that you should learn on day 1. Without being able to trace the execution of your programs, you're putting yourself at a huge disadvantage. Problems like this are ridiculously easy to find via an IDE's debugger.

Comment: @RandomDavis I attempted using a debugger but it wasn't clear to me, but as you said it is a tool I need to learn, I'm relatively new to coding (i'm 17) and just got this idea to program this typing game or whatever and thought I should give it a try. I plan on doing software engineering in uni tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the `difflib.SequenceMatcher` documentation, and it seems like `a` and `b` need to be sequences. You are giving it an `int` (`text_1`). If think you meant

```
seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=z, b=text_2)
```

Note: you should use random.choice to choose a random item from a list, like this `z = random.choice(words)` that way you dont need `text_1`